# CentOS7のブート時にフリーズし、CUIではログイン権限が無いと言われる

Tags: centos

CentOS Linux (3.10.0-123.20.1.e17.x86_64) 7 (Core) にて。

### 状態

上記を選択後、黒い画面の左上に以下の行が表示されたまま動きません。

```
[  OK  ] Started LSB: Start the ipr dump daemon.
[  OK  ] Started Dynamic System Tuning Daemon.（この行が無いこともある）
_
```

Ctrl + Alt + F2 からログインを試みたところ、以下のようになりました。

```
(host名) login:(アカウント名)
Password:(パスワード)

Last failed login...
There was 3...

Permission denied
```

Last... の行から Permission denied の行までは3秒ほど表示された後に消え、
loginのやり直しになります。

正しい管理者ユーザや通常ユーザのアカウントで
試してみたのですが、いずれも Permission denied でした。

### 心当たり

正常にOSが起動していたとき、sudo コマンドが面倒で常時 su 状態でした。
また、プログラミング時の事情で ulimit -n unlimited
（OSで一度に開けるファイル数を制限なし）にしていました。

このような症状に心当たりのある方はいらっしゃるでしょうか？
どうか宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: 隠す必要もないのに出力などを「...」のように省略すべきではありません。回答者はそこを手掛りにできるかもしれませんよ。

Answer (score 2):

- 必要なファイルを消してしまった。
- ディスクフルで新規プロセスを起動できない。

などが考えられます。
CD-ROM から起動し、レスキューモードでディスクの中身を調べると何かわかるかもしれません。

Answer (score 2):

正直いって、これだけだと何が悪いのかはわからないと思います。
CentOS7はsystemdを採用しているのでレスキューのやり方も以前とはかわっていて、ブート画面でいったん停止させ、コマンドを編集して`systemd.unit=rescue.target`を追加することで以前のシングルユーザーモード相当に入ります。
そこでログファイルを見るなり、`journalctl`コマンドで確認するなり、`systemctl`でどのターゲットが失敗しているか見るなりして原因追究します。

Answer (score 2):

IBMの[ドキュメント](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYKE2_7.0.0/com.ibm.java.lnx.70.doc/user/ulimits.html?lang=ja)でnofile制限について次のような記述がありました。

> この制限を /etc/security/limits.conf ファイル内で unlimited に設定すると、制限は 0
>   にリセットされます。この設定により、関連ユーザーまたはグループは新規プロセスを作成できなくなります。 ユーザーが root
>   ユーザーである場合、新規プロセスが作成できないため、システムはゆっくりとシャットダウンします。
>   この状態が発生すると、リカバリー・ディスクを使用して値をリセットする必要があります。

手元のCentos7環境でulimit -n unlimitedを実行すると「bash: ulimit: open files: limit を変更できません : 許可されていない操作です」と表示されます。

試しに /etc/sercurity/limits.confでunlimitにして再起動すると、同じ現象が再現しました。

```
*     soft    nofile    unlimited
*     hard    nofile    unlimited
```

ulimit -n unlimitedは一時的な変更ですので、再起動すると無効化されると思います。
limits.confまたはlimits.d配下の設定ファイルなどでファイル数の上限を変えている可能性はありませんか？

復元方法は、すでにコメントされている方がいらっしゃいますが、CD-ROM等から起動して、現在のディスクをマウントしてファイルを編集して下さい。